# does not contain definition for Content.ReadAsStringAsync() when using web client call

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, task-parallel-library, webclient

**this is my service**

```
public Task<NewsModel> GetNews(string query,string count)
{
    var task = Task<NewsModel>.Factory
        .StartNew(() => {
            var responseData = "";
            NewsModel list = new NewsModel();
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var uri = "Some URL";
            using (var response = client.GetAsync(uri)) {
                responseData =  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewsModel>(responseData);
                list.value.RemoveAll(item => item.image == null);
            }
            return list;

        });

    task.ContinueWith(t => {
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

    task.ContinueWith(t => {
        if (t.Exception == null)
            return;

        var ex = t.Exception.Flatten();

    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

    return task;
}
```

**compilation error**
[image]
**i am getting the above error when i try to compile**
**can you please tell me how can i use Content.ReadAsStringAsync() in the above functionality**

Comment: `var realResponse = await response.ConfigureAwait(false);` Then use `realResponse.Content`.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You are using the wrong object. If you check the docs or *every* HttpClient example you'll see that the methods are asynchronous and have to be awaited

Comment: BTW using `StartNew` and `ContinueWith` like this another problem. If you use `HttpClient` you can use `await` and simple `try/catch` blocks. `StartNew`, `ContinueWith` etc where *replaced* in most scenarios by `async/await`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those methods return Tasks so they should be awaited.

```
using (var response = await client.GetAsync(uri)) {
    responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewsModel>(responseData);
    list.value.RemoveAll(item => item.image == null);
}
```

In fact that entire method should be refactored to use async/await

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public async Task<NewsModel> GetNews(string query, string count) {
    NewsModel list = new NewsModel();
    var uri = "Some URL";
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(uri)) {
        var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewsModel>(responseData);
        list.value.RemoveAll(item => item.image == null);
    }
    return list;
}
```